# Angular 4 router-outlet css

Tags: javascript, angular, router-outlet

With the deprecation of all three of `/deep/`, `>>>`, and `::ng-deep` how do I style the router-outlet siblings?

I used to `:host /deep/ router-outlet + * {height: 100%}` before they announced their intention to drop support for the above selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

```
:host ::ng-deep router-outlet + * {height: 100%}
```

or just

```
::ng-deep router-outlet + * {height: 100%}
```

should still work

`::ng-deep` is deprecated but with a different meaning than `/deep/` and `>>>`. `/deep/` and `>>>` were deprecated because browsers and especially SASS stopped supporting them. They agreed on supporting `::ng-deep` instead.

`::ng-deep` is deprecated because eventually all browsers will support native shadow DOM and probably some way of styling them, and then `::ng-deep` will become obsolete.